# How to display chrome like console error inside my webpage div container

Tags: javascript, html, console.log

How i display chrome like console system inside my website.where we can see all type of error encountered in webpage.it must be display realtime errors at a time like chrome console.

no need to display console.log function result. Only need error message

I try some code but that is not showing error